# Unable to perform MDL discretization

Tags: orange

I have installed orange 2.7.8 on my windows 8. On loading the CSV file, it fails to recognize the Class Attribute hence I am unable to perform MDL discretization. Please let me know how to select a particular attribute as Class using orange.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify otherwise, the last column is the class.

What is the file extension? Can you paste the first few lines?